# Fingerprint Scanner Support for lower android versions

Tags: android, fingerprint

Shall I know from which API FingerprintManager is supporting for android?

Actually I am trying to authenticate app from finger print scan.

So I need to know from which version API it is supporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shall I know from which API FingerprintManager is supporting for android?

API Level 23 (Android 6.0). The JavaDocs for every Android SDK class note what API level the class was added in, along with the API levels that methods, fields, etc. were added in.

Comment: API Level 23 ? okay what about for lower version like lollipop, kitkat? 
can you share JavaDocs link which may helpful.

Comment: you can go through this link http://www.secugen.com/products/sdk_pro.htm, this is third party library for below API Level 23.

Comment: @NaveenKumarM: "okay what about for lower version like lollipop, kitkat?" -- there is no official support for fingerprints in Android prior to API Level 23. Generally speaking, few devices have fingerprint sensors. Those that do may have SDKs from their device manufacturers. "can you share JavaDocs link" -- if you use a search engine to search for `android fingerprintmanager`, you will find [the JavaDocs for that class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare - How to support fingerprint on OnePlus 2 because it has version 5.1?

Comment: @CommonsWare I am trying to implement the fingerprint scanner. Its working fine on device having marshmellow and more. But app is crashing on lower veriosn. I am checking the version using this.
if (currentapiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) .

I am getting error on API level 19:
java.lang.VerifyError

What to do in this case. Can you help me.

Comment: @Kishan: I recommend that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, with a [mcve] and the full Java stack trace.