# Android Fingerprint Scanner Api

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I want to use Android Finger Print Scanner API in my Android application.But as I am I found, I need to have android marshmallow OS to use this feature.

I also downloaded sample app from android official site, and they have also mentioned min required sdk as 23.

So is that mean that, I cant use this API before 23?
Even trustworthy Reference of **CommonsWare** suggests its not possible
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32563262/fingerprint-scanner-support-for-lower-android-versions`
If I am right that, its must have android marshmallow to support finger print scanner, How can I provide support of Finger Print Scanner function to pre marshmallow?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what type of app you are building/have.

There are some options.

1. Use fingerprint only on API level 23 and implement some other security measure on API level lower than 23
2. Check your app statistics to determine the commonly used devices and check for device specific fingerprint integration. (Samsung has SDK for fingerprinting if the device has a scanner built in.) 
   Use the Android implementation on API level 23 and the device specific SDK for devices lower than API 23.
3. Don't use fingerprint at all.

Comment: You have good solutions man.
But I need to code this function for every device , if I am using device specific sdk
do you have information regarding common third party sdk?

Comment: Yes it is not easy. First you need to decide if you really need it or you want to add it because it's trending now. I am not sure about common third party sdk because usually the device manufacturer needs to integrate the support in the Android itself, then to provide and sdk for us to be able to access those low level APIs, then somebody needs to write an wrapper for all those SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

for Device with OS API lower than API 23, just access manufacturer website and find "SDK", "API", ... to find fingerprint sdk (lib file) to use for your app.
For Sky, it is PantechFingerprint SDK (Ex: Sky A890) : https://github.com/pantechfingerprint/PantechFingerSDK
For Samsung, it is Pass SDK : http://developer.samsung.com/sensor-extension#pass
I don't know FingerPrintManger of Android OS API 23 and above will works properly with all kind of FingerPrint sensor of a lot of smart phone on the market. I even haven't any Android 6.0 Phone to check. Too bad for a developer like me.